# Reading Post body in a request TO a React app

Tags: reactjs, http-post

I googled Post requests for React but all I get are examples of React SENDING a Post request. I need to be able to read Post requests going TO a react app. I have one example of a Get request going to React where the params are in this.props.location.search. I need the same thing but for Post.

Comment: React runs on the clients side, requests go to the server side. So there are no requests TO react.

Comment: you can use chrome developer console to check it.
Right click on website -> click inspect element -> opened developer console -> click Network tab -> there you can see all the API request and related stuff

Comment: Hi, what I have observed is there is an object in React that has the params from the Get request to it's server(this.props.location.search). How do I find the params from a Post request to the server React is running on? Is it just the same search object used for Get?